# how to obtain a CCSprite's width and height in cocos2d for iphone

Tags: iphone, sprite, dimensions, ccsprite

That's the question xD

Given an instance of a CCSprite in cocos2d in iphone, what method can I use to obtain the image width and height?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The CCSprite class has a bounding box property that's a CGRect:

```
  CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"file.png"];
  int width = [sprite boundingBox].size.width;
```

I added a width and height methods to my CCSprite subclass.

```
-(CGFloat) width
{
    return [self boundingBox].size.width;
}

-(CGFloat) height
{
    return [self boundingBox].size.height;
}
```

Answer (score 39):

raw width:
`sprite.contentSize.width`

raw height:
`sprite.contentSize.height`

current width: 
`sprite.contentSize.width * sprite.scaleX`

current height: 
`sprite.contentSize.height * sprite.scaleY`

Comment: This should be the right accepted answer even though robterrell's answer also gives the right values. This one is better though.

Comment: The first one has a capitalization error, it's sprite.contentSize.width rather than sprite.contentsize.width

Comment: Does contentSize take rotation into account?

Answer (score 0):

IN cocos2d-x

```
sprite->boundingBox().size.width;

sprite->boundingBox().size.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

In cocos2d-x v3.x, `boundingBox` is deprecated in the *Node* class (i.e. the super class of *Sprite*). Use the following code instead:

```
auto spriteWidth = sprite->getTextureRect().size.width;
auto spriteHeight = sprite->getTextureRect().size.height;
```

or

```
auto spriteWidth = sprite->getContentSize().width;
auto spriteHeight = sprite->getContentSize().height;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Answer for 2018 (Cocos2d-x v3.x:)

The other answers are incomplete and out-of-date.

Note that I'm using JavaScript below along with [destructuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Be sure to view the [Cocos API documentation](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/api-ref/) for your language implementation.

---

### getBoundingBox()

Gives you the:

- Scaled size (the size after `setScale()` is applied to the sprite).
- Coordinates of sprite on the screen. Note that the default `anchorPoint` for sprites is (0.5, 0.5), while this coordinate represents the (0, 0) position. In other words, if the anchorPoint is set at the default, then `getBoundingBox().x` + `getBoundingBox().width` / 2 = `getPosition().x` (the x value you set in `setPosition()`).

Example:

```
const boundingBox = sprite.getBoundingBox();
const { x, y, width, height } = boundingBox;
```

### getContentSize()

Gives you the:

- Unscaled size.

Example:

```
const contentSize = sprite.getContentSize();
const { x, y } = contentSize;
```

### getTextureRect()

Gives you the:

- Unscaled size.
- Coordinates of sprite on the texture from which it is extracted (i.e. sprite sheet)

Example:

```
const textureRect = sprite.getTextureRect();
const { x, y, width, height } = textureRect;
```