# Strange positioning of CCSprites from pvr texture

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I use Kobold2D + TexturePacker (both are the last version at this moment).

When I create an CCSprite object using the spriteWithFile: method, and place as it should, it looks fine.

```
CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"dir_bg.png"];
background.position = CGPointMake(screenSize.width - background.texture.contentSize.width / 2 - 10, background.texture.contentSize.height / 2 + 10);

[self addChild:background];

controller = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"dir_big.png"];
controller.position = background.position;

[self addChild:controller];
```

[image: spriteWithFile:]

But with a different method, with the loading of textures using spriteWithSpriteFrameName:, the object is not placed as it should.

```
[CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"Textures.plist"];

CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

background = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"dir_bg.png"];
background.position = CGPointMake(screenSize.width - background.texture.contentSize.width / 2 - 10, background.texture.contentSize.height / 2 + 10);

[self addChild:background];

controller = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"dir_big.png"];
controller.position = background.position;

[self addChild:controller];
```

[image: spriteWithSpriteFrameName:]

Why?

Comment: you are loading 3 sprites: the background plus the 2 different "control" sprites; this is what I read in the 2 images you posted; on the other hand, I can only see two calls to `spriteWithFile`. am I missing anything?

Comment: Some TexturePacker settings may cause this, for example the Trim setting (don't use flush position). Check that the sprite properties are identical, mainly position, anchorPoint and contentSize. If they differ, update your question.

Comment: sergio, these calls for only one CCNode of direction control, with two CCSprites -- background and wheel. In general, there are CCLayer with background of the map, and two CCNodes with CCSprites.

Comment: LearnCocos2D, I tried different settings, in particular with none/trim/crop, but they did not produce any effect, still appear shifted. Maybe I'm missing something? What do you mean by "Check that the sprite properties are identical, mainly position, anchorPoint and contentSize."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead `background.texture.contentSize.width` use `background.contentSize.width` et cetera.

Source: [how to obtain a CCSprite's width and height in cocos2d for iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503903/how-to-obtain-a-ccsprites-width-and-height-in-cocos2d-for-iphone)